# How to use AWS API Gateway without https redirect

Tags: http, arduino, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to call api gateway endpoint and invoke lambda function from arduino. 
Arduino does't support https protocol, I can use only insecure http.

This is a response from endpoint:

```
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
X-Cache: Redirect from cloudfront
X-Amz-Cf-Id: N_y2-yhi7hT4-RHzI8SdUcMjUYfLYCMO3rX3d4qe3Y-TcAAdIG269A==
Connection: Close
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2017 09:48:51 GMT
Location: https://id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/pay
Server: CloudFront
Via: 1.1 4cef090fba24867bb1a518bc7c5a1e98.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), 1.1 Comverse 6.2.24
Content-Length: 183
```

Is there any way to solve this issue to AWS side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now, API Gateway doesn't support insecure HTTP Rest APIs.

Comment: That's correct. I've researched the topic but no success. thanks for the answer.